# how to save the form fields in 2 tables using laravel

Tags: database, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I am novice to laravel.I need to save the form field one in one table and other in other table in laravel.These two tables having the foreign key reference.In one table data is saved but the other one cannot save in database.Can anyone suggest for this?

Advance Thanks

table question:
id,
exam_id,
question

table answer:
id,
question_id,
options,
answers

model 1:

```
     namespace App;

     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

     class Question extends Model
        {
         protected $table='question'; 

      public function answer()
       { 
    return $this->hasMany('Answer');
      }
      }
```

model 2:

```
<?php

    namespace App;
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Answer extends Model 
   {

      protected $table='answer'; 


       public function question()
  {
     return $this->BelongsTo('Question');
    }

       }
```

**add question page**

```
     public function add_question()
     {
     $exam =DB::table('exam')->select(array('id', 'exam_name'))->get();
     return view('add_question')->with('exam',$exam);
     }  
     //it shows the form page
```

**validate and save question and answer details to the database**

```
     public function validate_question()
          {
     $rules = array(
       'question'=>'required|max:300'

      );
         $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
          {
      return edirect::back()->withErrors($validator,'login')->withInput(Input::except('question'));

             } 
            else
           {
           $question =new  Question;
          $question->exam_id   = Input::get('exam_id');
         $question->question  = Input::get('question');
           $question->save();
       if($question->save()){
        $answer  =new Answer;
         $answer ->options  = Input::get('options');
     $answer ->answers  = Input::get('answers');
       $question->answer()->save($answer);
    }
         }

        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created question record!');
       return Redirect::to('question');
       }
```

I got error :

FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 261: Class 'App\Answer' not found.

Please any one suggest for this

Comment: And what did you already try?

Comment: provide your existence code for fix you problem!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.Amit and Mr.Rimon.I included my code.What mistake i done.Can you please suggest for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Answer` model you have namespaced it twice (by accident perhaps):

```
namespace App;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Obviously your model lives in the `App` directory, rather than `Controllers`, so just delete the second line.

Also, in referencing the relationship you need to specify the proper path, `App\Question` rather than `Question`. On that note the same goes in your `Question` model.

Your `Answer` model should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model 
{  
    protected $table='answer'; 

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\Question');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank u Mr.James for your reply.I used your code i got this error:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answers' in 'field list' (SQL: update `question` set `id` = , `question` = ques, `answers` = , `options` = opt where `id` is null).How to save it to the database.Please suggest me